# Adding the root in a simple Rails app gives javascript error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'm following a simple Ruby on Rails example with a simple Hello World page but when I run it I get an error in the application.html.erb page at this line:

```
<%= javascript_include_tag 'application', 'data-turbolinks-track' => true %>
```

The only thing I changed was in the routes.rb file. I unremmed the root line which now has:

```
root 'welcome#index'
```

The controller name is welcome and the action name is index (I generated them by typing 'rails generate controller welcome index').

When I comment back the line, everything works. What did I do wrong in my first ever controller\action?

Here is the error I get in the browser:

Showing C:/temp/blog/app/views/layouts/application.html.erb where line #6 raised:

TypeError: Object doesn't support this property or method
  (in C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.1.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/turbolinks-2.5.3/lib/assets/javascripts/turbolinks.js.coffee)

In the Chrome console it gives :

Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 500 (Internal Server Error)

http://localhost:3000/welcome/index

Comment: Can you spot where the error is coming from in a browser inspector, e.g. firebug in firefox.

Comment: Post the contents of the error.

Comment: Are you using windows 7?

Answer (score 1):

This could be a Coffee script version issue, 
in your Gemfile, use

```
gem 'coffee-script-source', '1.8.0'
```

then bundle, see if that works.

Comment: you don't run this from the commad line, you add that line to the Gemfile, copy/paste. then from the terminal you run bundle

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem.  I was using coffee-script-source 1.9.1.1, when I switched to 1.8.0, my jquery was loading fine and app was working correctly.  I guess there is a bug for Windows OS.